# Backbone.js - Where to define view helpers?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I've been kicking the tyres of Backbone.js and having a play around in recent weeks, so a bit of a noob question...

What is the 'correct' way to define and use view helpers in backbone.js?

As far as I can work out, the only real place to define helpers to use in your templates is on the model or collection itself. However, when that helper is directly returning HTML, this begins to feel a little dirty.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are a few different places that I put view helpers with Backbone.js:

**If the helper is specific to a certain view, put it right in the view definition:**

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  events: {
    ...
  },

  initialize: function() { ... },

  helperOne: function() {
    // Helper code
  },

  anotherHelper: function() {
    // Helper code
  },

  render: function() { 
    ... this.helperOne() ...
  }
});
```

**If the helper will be used by all views, extend the Backbone View class so that all views inherit this function:**

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, {
  helper: function() {
    // Helper code
  }
}
```

**If you need more complicated sharing of helpers between views, have views extend each other:**

```
var MyOtherView = MyView.extend({

  // ...

  render: function() { 
    ... this.helperOne() ...
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what is best practice (or if there is an established best practice), but these patterns seem fairly clean and work well.

Comment: It is also possible to do Mixins (i.e. have the class "mixin" methods from a collection of classes as needed), and even aspect-oriented programming (have a single function call override a collection of classes, wrapping a target method with another method).

Comment: Hmm, using `this` within `extend` didn't work for me, but `this.__proto__` did work. Shouldn't `__proto__` methods work with just `this`? Eg `this.myMethod()` as opposed to `this.__proto__.myMethod()`. For me, the latter works but the former fails.

Comment: Thanks for this, now that I know how to extend the backbone view class I can remove my ridiculous amount of duplicated functions.

Comment: awesome, I've found myself writing a lot of duplicate helper functions, and I'm definitely going use the second method, but  can you give an example of where you might use the third method you showed?

Answer (score 0):

As you build bigger Backbone apps, you'll probably want to namespace everything. Then you will have a place for global helpers. I haven't made the perfect namespace setup yet. But right now I'm doing something like this:

```
brainswap:{
  appView: {},          <== Reference to instantiated AppView class.
  classes = {           <== Namespace for all custom Backbone classes.
    views : {},
    models : {},
    collections: {},
    controllers : {},
    Router: null
  },
  models: {},          <== Instantiated models.
  controllers: {},     <== Instantiated controllers.
  router: {},          <== Instantiated routers.
  helpers: {},         <== Reusable helper platform methods.
  currentView: {},     <== A reference to the current view so that we can destroy it.
  init: function(){}   <== Bootstrap code to start app.
}
```

My view classes look something like this:

```
brainswap.classes.views.profile.contact = brainswap.classes.views.profile.base.extend({...
```

My controller is the object that instantiates new views (and places a reference in `currentView`. Remember you should always remove your last view so the previous views events all get unbinded and your reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution (CoffeeScript)

```
Backbone.View::handlebarsTemplate = (templateName) ->
  Handlebars.compile $(templateName).html()
```

Then you can use that in your view:

```
Yourcoolapp.Views.ThingsIndex extends Backbone.view

  initialize: ->
    @template = this.handlebarsTemplate("#hb_template")
    # etc...

  someMethod: =>
    @template = this.handlebarsTemplate("#hb_other")
```